# Java hot reload in JHipster

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jhipster

I have the JHipster sample app running with the following hot reload instruction:

```
-javaagent:spring_loaded/springloaded-jhipster.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=plugins=io.github.jhipster.loaded.instrument.JHipsterLoadtimeInstrumentationPlugin
```

I inserted the following into getCurrentSessions() in  com.mycompany.myapp.web.rest.AccountResource to test the hot reloading:

```
log.debug("Getting the current open sessions...");
```

I'm not seeing the debug message show up.  I'm running this in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctr+f9 or cmnd+f9 (if you are on a Mac) after your code changes.It should tell to Intellij to refresh your jar and you should see your log